# htaccess moved to vhost not playing nice

Tags: apache, redirect, vhosts

I wanted to move my .htaccess file - redirects into my vhost conf file...

This was working - but the htaccess redirects were not...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName  dev.x.com
ServerAlias dev.x.com
DocumentRoot    "C:/wwwroot/x"
Alias       /modules/    "C:/wwwroot/x/_my_modules/"
ErrorLog    "C:/wwwroot/x/_my_logs/error.log"
CustomLog   "C:/wwwroot/x/_my_logs/access.log" combined
<Directory  "C:/wwwroot/x/_my_logs/" >
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Satisfy all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then i did this -

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  dev.x.com
    ServerAlias dev.x.com
    DocumentRoot    "C:/wwwroot/x"
    Alias       /modules/    "C:/wwwroot/x/_my_modules/"
    ErrorLog    "C:/wwwroot/x/_my_logs/error.log"
    CustomLog   "C:/wwwroot/x/_my_logs/access.log" combined
    <Directory  "C:/wwwroot/x/_my_logs/" >
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Satisfy all
    </Directory>

    RewriteEngine on

    # if requested URI is not a file and not a directory
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    # externally redirect to /newLocation/{URI}
    # RewriteRule (.*) index.php?_req=$1 [L]

    # could use a redirect to a new directory --- 
    RewriteRule ^ /_mf_modules%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

My objective was this:
I wanted any "directory" request - that didn't exist - to be rerouted to a directory of that name in the _my_modules dir.

IF a file did not exist I wanted to redirect to the to a directory of that name in the _my_modules dir.

So if www.x.com/xxx was the url... and 'xxx' dir didn't exist, I'd redirect to www.x.com/_my_modules/xxx

and like wise if www.x.com/xxx.php was requested - but xxx.php DIDN'T exist, they wou be redirected to www.x.com/_my_modules/xxx

- however (even though there is an index.php in each dir) these always results in th eURL redirecting to this...

  The requested URL /modules/modules/modules/modules/modules/modules/modules/modules/modules/modules/modules/modules/modules/modules/modules/modules/modules/modules/modules/_my_modules/ was not found on this server.

So I got fed up and changed the vhost file back to what I had to begin with, restarted Apache, and it's still redirecting, I can't get rid of the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You can move the RewriteRules from a .htaccess to the VirtualHost environment by putting them in a `<Directory>` environment in your vhost configuration.

In your case, try to cut and paste your rewrite rules in `<Directory  "C:/wwwroot/x/_my_logs/" >`

If you really want to put them in the VirtualHost environment, you have to modify the paths in them: RewriteRules in .htaccess or  are relative to the directory, RewriteRules in the VirtualHost are absolute to the root of the filesystem or the DocumentRoot.

rewritecond example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

should be in vhost:

```
RewriteCond /your/documentroot/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

rewriterule example:

```
RewriteRule (.*) /your/documentroot/index.php?_req=$1 [L]
```

should be in vhost:

```
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?_req=$1 [L]
```